# Android Intent (or code) to open email composer in (outlook, gmail)

Tags: android, android-intent

I would like to know how to open the Activity for composing email in gmail or outlook. By now I only know ho to be redirected to for instance gmail but I would also open the "composer" (or whatever) and add an email address. I've already tried with:

```
 intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL  , new String[]{"recipient@example.com"});
```

but doesnot work

full source to the test-app

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String GOOGLE_MAIL = "com.google.android.gm";
private static final String OUTLOOK = "com.microsoft.office.outlook";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    test(GOOGLE_MAIL);

}


private void test(String mail) {

    Intent intent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(mail);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL  , new String[]{"recipient@example.com"});
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```java
protected void sendEmail() {
  Log.i("Send email", "");

  String[] TO = {"someone@gmail.com"};
  String[] CC = {"xyz@gmail.com"};
  Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
  emailIntent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));
  emailIntent.setType("text/plain");


  emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, TO);
  emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_CC, CC);
  emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Your subject");
  emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Email message goes here");

  try {
     startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."));
     finish();
     Log.i("Finished sending email...", "");
  } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
     Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, 
     "There is no email client installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
}
```